# Prove that if $\gcd(m, n) > 1$, then there do not exist integers $x, y$ so that $mx + ny = 1$.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I've been stuck on this one for awhile, and I thought that if I did a contradiction: if $\gcd(m,n) > 1$ then for all integers $x,y$,  $ax + ny \neq 1$. I could simply prove it wrong by giving an example. But I've got a feeling that I'm missing something that makes this not work, But I don't know what else to do.

Comment: `if I did a contradiction` But what you wrote next is the wrong premise for a proof by contradiction. Instead, you'd start with something like "*suppose $\gcd(m,n) \ge 2$ and $mx+ny=1$ then...*".

Comment: The negation of $p \implies q$ is "p and not q". The statement you wrote is "(not p) implies q"

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Comment: By the linked dupe, since $\,m,n\,$ are multiples of the gcd so too is their integral linear combination $\,mx+ny = 1,\,$ so the gcd $= 1.\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

As the comments noted, the contradiction assumptions in the original question are not correct.  The correct assumption (and some hints of how to proceed) follow:

Suppose that $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$ and suppose that there exist integers $x$ and $y$ so that $mx+ny=1$.  Since $d$ divides both $m$ and $n$ (since it is the greatest common *divisor* of them), $d$ divides the LHS.  So $d$ divides the RHS.  Now, can you find a contradiction?

Comment: Excellent hint.

Comment: Ahh I see! since the only number which divides 1 is 1, no such d can exist! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$ divides  $mx+ny$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$, and only $1$ divides $1$.